# After setting PDC to external time source, do I have to perform a similar action for every pc/server to sync with PDC?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

Server 2012 R2 as PDC, Hyper-V servers and Win 7/8 workstations

I have my PDC synchronized to an external time source.  What is my next step in getting my domain synchronized with regard to the PDC's time?  I do have some links I've looked at:  [link1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2007/09/04/keeping-the-domain-on-time.aspx), [link2](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/configuring-time-synchronization-for-all-computers-in-windows-domain/)

Are these good processes to follow, or is there a better method to follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be a little more technically precise: Each DC that doesn't hold the PDC Emulator role will sync with the DC that does hold the PDC Emulator role. Every other domain joined computer will sync with whichever DC authenticates it, which is not necessarily the PDCe. You do not need to manually configure any non-PDCe DC or member computer.

Comment: Actually, each DC in the same AD site as the PDCe will sync from it, with DCs in other sites syncing from the bridgehead. But for all intents and purposes, this answer is close enough :)

Comment: NTP source selection uses the DC locator process.

Comment: @Alan: As MDMarra and Ryan Ries both point out, there's more going on under the covers in relation to domain time synchronization. I kept my answer simple so as not to overwhelm you with too much info but you can read more about how the Windows Time Service works here. The article is older but should still hold up - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, they will automatically synch with the PDC assuming it's the PDC emulator for the root domain in your forest (if you only have one domain you're good). Do NOT manually synch time for domain members, as long as the DC with the PDCe FSMO is syncing externally you should be set*

*if the Hypervisor your running on is old or the Hyper-V server is really overworked the PDCe may lag a bit but that would be true for the other boxes on it so should work out in the end anyways.